# Filter is not showing right categories

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to make work filter based on last column. Last Column is Category and when I press in option>select I need to show just that one category and hide others, but for now when I click nothing happen and don't have idea why.

```js
highlightRows = () => {
    let oddRows = document.querySelectorAll('tbody > tr.show')
    oddRows.forEach((row, index)=> {
        if (index % 2 == 0) {
            row.style.background = '#f1f1f1'
        } else {
            row.style.background = '#fff'
        }
    })
}
const filterOptions = () => {
    const option = document.querySelector("#filter").value;
    const selection = option.replace('&', '')
  const rows = document.querySelectorAll("#body1 > tr");
  console.log(rows.length);
    
    rows.forEach(row => {
        let td = row.querySelector("td:last-child");
        let filter = td.innerText.replace('&', '');
        if (filter === selection) {
            row.className = 'show'
        } else {
            row.className = 'hidden'
        }
    });
    highlightRows()
};
document.getElementById("filter").addEventListener("change", filterOptions);
```

```css
table.vypis {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table.vypis > caption {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: .5em 0 .75em;
}

table.vypis > tr.vypis-riadok {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: .35em;
}

table.vypis th,
table.vypis td {
  padding: .625em;
  text-align: center;
}

table.vypis th {
  font-size: .85em;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  table.vypis {
    border: 0;
  }

  table.vypis > caption {
    font-size: 1.3em;
  }
  
  table.vypis > thead {
    border: none;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
  }
  
  table.vypis tr {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: .625em;
  }
  
  table.vypis td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    font-size: .8em;
    text-align: right;
  }
  
  table.vypis td::before {
    /*
    * aria-label has no advantage, it won't be read inside a table
    content: attr(aria-label);
    */
    content: attr(data-label);
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  
  table.vypis td:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
  <div class="table-filters">
        <select id="filter">
          <option disabled selected value="none">Categories</option>
          <option>Home</option>
          <option>Others</option>
          <option>Hobby</option>
          <option>Garden</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <table class="vypis">
        <caption>Account</caption>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Referencia</th>
            <th scope="col">Dátum</th>
            <th scope="col">Suma</th>
            <th scope="col">Kategória</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="body1">
          <tr class="vypis-riadok">
            <td scope="row" data-label="Referencia">[[X04_textovy_popis_obycajne]]</td>
            <td data-label="Dátum">[[X02_riadok_1_datum]]</td>
            <td data-label="Suma">[[X08_riadok_1_suma]] €</td>
            <td data-label="Kategória">[[kategoria]]</td>
          </tr>

          <tr class="vypis-riadok">
            <td scope="row" data-label="Referencia">[[X04_textovy_popis_obycajne]]</td>
            <td data-label="Dátum">[[X02_riadok_1_datum]]</td>
            <td data-label="Suma">[[X08_riadok_1_suma]] €</td>
            <td data-label="Kategória">Garden</td>
          </tr>
          
          <tr class="vypis-riadok">
            <td scope="row" data-label="Referencia">[[X04_textovy_popis_obycajne]]</td>
            <td data-label="Dátum">[[X02_riadok_1_datum]]</td>
            <td data-label="Suma">[[X08_riadok_1_suma]] €</td>
            <td data-label="Kategória">Home</td>
          </tr>
          
          <tr class="vypis-riadok">
            <td scope="row" data-label="Referencia">[[X04_textovy_popis_obycajne]]</td>
            <td data-label="Dátum">[[X02_riadok_1_datum]]</td>
            <td data-label="Suma">[[X08_riadok_1_suma]] €</td>
            <td data-label="Kategória">Hobby</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is in your query for `tbody` you write `#body1` so it will query element with ID `body1` while in your html code, `tbody` is with class `body1` not id

```
const rows = document.querySelectorAll("#body1 > tr"); // <--- will select element with id="body1"
```

your HTML code:

```
   ...
   </thead>
    <tbody class="body1"> <!--body is using attribute class -->
      <tr class="vypis-riadok">
   ...
```

what you should do is use class query selector, change `#` into `.`

```
const rows = document.querySelectorAll(".body1 > tr"); // <--- will select element with class="body1"
```

after that your javascript code should be fine, now add css style for `show` and `hidden` class

```
.hidden{
 display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

should be  because I got defined select by ID

Comment: Please use answers only to answer the question in full. If you want to add to your question, edit your question. If you want to answer your own question, please include details into how this text answers the question.